# i want to insert and update the quantity of the specific item id

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

If the item id  is already exist ,the quantity should ne added with tha incoming quanity else if the id did not exist insert the id and the quantity

my_table:

```
if  
item_id=array(24,25);

quantity=array(10,2);
```

this will be inserted to the table:

```
else if 

item_id=array(22,23);
quantity=array(2,4);
```

the quantity must be add to the existing item

**auto_id | item_id | quantity**

```
 1        22         12   
 2        23         3
```

this is an array type of item id and quantity.Sorry for my english and thanks,

```
foreach($item_id as $row => $id){

        $items_id = $id;
            foreach($quantity as $row => $id2){
            $qty = $id2;
                $values[] = array(
                        array("item_id" => $items_id,
                        "quantity" => $qty));
                $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT ip_id FROM my_table WHERE item_id = '".$items_id."'");      
                if($sql->num_rows() > 0){

                    $this->db->query("UPDATE my_table SET quantity=quantity+'".$qty."' WHERE item_id='".$items_id."'");
                }else{    
                    $this->db->insert_batch('my_table',$values);
                }
            }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, You're doing it wrong by using 2 foreach statements, You're picking up the same 2 quantities for each id in your example above, You should be using "array_combine" to make an array of the keys from the first one & values from the second then do a single foreach which would give you the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

Skip all of that code and use a simple [`ON DUPLICATE KEY ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) construct:

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (id, quantity) VALUES ($id, $quantity)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity=quantity+VALUES(quantity)
```

Comment: Just make sure your id column is a primary key.. most likely is but just a reminder.

Comment: the item_id inserts duplicate values,also the quantity